# How to host ionic app as website on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created Android mobile app using ionic and Cordova. Now I need to host this app as a website. I don't have any knowledge regarding hosting web app. Please help in this.

Comment: You can build for browser. But not sure where you want to host, e dedicated server is different with host on azure web app, or AWS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43701116/2490286

Answer (score 1):

Given the project structure and given that Ionic uses similar structure as angular which ships out from the /dist directory, ionic ships out the projects final / production source codes from the /www directory.

However, checkout a similar question here: [How to host an Ionic app in web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546669/how-to-host-an-ionic-app-in-web)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this docker file to compile and serve the project using nginx

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build
ARG ENVIRONMENT=stage  # stage prod
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install -g ionic
RUN npm install
RUN echo "Building for environment: $ENVIRONMENT"
COPY ./ /app/
RUN NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=512 && npm run build --prod
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The problem i have in this moment with this deployment is that ionic app changes route (app.com/home or app.com/tab1) and once I refresh, the route cannot be reached (error 404). It is Nginx config issue.

Answer (score -5):

If using NodeJs, you can run app via command line:

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: That just shows you your apk for testing, I think thats not what user is asking, sorry if rude.

Comment: ionic serve will locally run the app on browser. But I need to host app at organization level. So, will have to deploy it on server, but not understanding how to do it

Comment: If you want deploy app as a website, easy. You copy all files and folders in folder `\www` in root folder on server.